# how to specify the data source of a report in a url

Tags: looker-studio

If I design a report based on some data source, lets say an spreadsheet from google sheets.

but then I want to reuse this report on a different sheet, can I do this without actually editing the report? Can I specify the source somehow in the URL?
Then all I need to do to reuse the report is upload new sheets to my google drive and then connect them to the report by specifying them in the URL.

Is this possible? Or is there a better way to do it?

(I'm googling, but I cannot find out how to reuse reports without actually manually editing them).

---

so there does seem to be something called "Custom JSON/CSV/XML" by Supermetrics.
and you seem to be able to specify the url as a parameter somehow. If someone has done this and succeeded/failed, or knows of a walkthrough/tutorial, or a variation on this theme then that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Using default connectors, you can't change the Data Source using parameters.

You may try to create a [community connector](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/build) with a parameter to set the desired resource, but I don't think it will fit your needs or worth the effort (you'll still need to edit the report to change the parameter).

However, when you click to copy/duplicate a report, it prompt you to select new sources for each Data Source in your report.  It will copy-then-edit your report anyway, but it is a friendly interface.  Maybe you should try this.